# Unable to delete value character from input reactjs

Tags: reactjs, input, user-input, react-bootstrap, erase

I cannot seem to delete the last character of the value I input.

**For example:**
I will type in the input field: "syEmail@mail.com" and want to delete it all to rewrite it. I can backspace all of them without a problem, untill I get to the last character. So the input field now has: "s".

p.s. I am using react-bootstrap validation on top of the validation I wrote myself. This problem started when I wrote the conditional of the value field beïng empty in handleChange.

I have deleted all of the other code to hopefully help get a clear picture of what is going on. If I'm missing something please let me know.

The const below have more than just these objects, but for this problem its not relevant. :

```
const [validation, setValidation] = useState({email: "notActive"}); 
const [messages, setMessages] = useState({ errormessageEmail: '' });
const [account, setAccount] = useState({ createEmail: ""});
```

useEffect to validate if the email has the right characters

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (validation.email === "active") {
            let err = '';
            const emailRegex = new RegExp("[^\\.\\s@:](?:[^\\s@:]*[^\\s@:\\.])?@[^\\.\\s@]+(?:\\.[^\\.\\s@]+)+(?:\\.[^\\.\\s@]+)*");
            if (emailRegex.test(account.createEmail)) {
                err = false;
                setMessages(prevState => ({ ...prevState, errormessageEmail: err }))
                setValidation(prevState => ({ ...prevState, email: true }));
            } else {
                err = <div className="text-start">{translated.errorMail}</div>
                setMessages(prevState => ({ ...prevState, errormessageEmail: err }))
                setValidation(prevState => ({ ...prevState, email: false }));
            }
        }
    }, [account.createEmail, validation.email, translated.errorMail]);
```

handleChange:

```
        const handleChange = (e, i) => {
            const { name, value, type } = e.target;
                if (name === 'createEmail') {
                    if (value === '') {
                        setValidation(prevState => ({ ...prevState, email: false }));
                    } else {
                        setAccount(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
                        setValidation(prevState => ({ ...prevState, email: "active" }));
                    }
                }
        }
```

inputfield:

```
                                        <Form.Group as={Row}>
                                            <Form.Control
                                                name="createEmail"
                                                type="email"
                                                className={validation.email === true ? "form-control is-valid" : validation.email === false || validation.email === "active" ? "form-control is-invalid" : null}
                                                placeholder={props.t('login:CreateEmail')}
                                                value={account.createEmail}
                                                onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                                                required />
                                            {messages.errormessageEmail ?
                                                < Alert className="no-margin-bttm nav-button-full" variant="danger">{messages.errormessageEmail}</Alert>
                                                : null}
                                        </Form.Group>
```

Can anyone please tell me why it's working like this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try updating internal state via `setAccount` in case that `value === ''`

Comment: Thank you @Steve, I can't believe I missed that :P

Comment: Great to hear that it works now. I will quickly add an answer so this question is not shown as open anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input field has the value `account.createEmail`. This value was initialized by `useState` with an empty string. It can later on be changed with the method `setAccount`.

However, this method is not called in `handleChange` listener in case that `value === ''`.

That explains why internal state is not updated and the input field cannot reflect any changes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in the `handleChange` when the `value === ''` you are updating the validation to be false, but you aren't updating the value of the input with the new value (""). so you still have the last previous value, which is 's'.

So you should just move the updating of then `setAccount` outside of the if so you always update the value of the input.

like this

```
const handleChange = (e, i) => {
    const { name, value} = e.target;
    if (name === 'createEmail') {
      setAccount(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
      if (value === '') {
        setValidation(prevState => ({ ...prevState, email: false }));
      } else {
        setValidation(prevState => ({ ...prevState, email: "active" }));
      }
    }
}
```

or even better use a ternary operator instead of the if else

```
const handleChange = (e, i) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    if (name === 'createEmail') {
      setAccount(prevState => ({ ...prevState, [name]: value }));
      setValidation(prevState => ({ ...prevState, email: !value ? false: "active"}));

    }
}
```